# Поиск по вектору состоящему из объектов

Tags: c++, поиск

Пусть есть:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<ClassAAA> SHP_ClassAAA;

class ClassBBB : public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
~~~~~~~
private:
std::vector<SHP_ClassAAA> objAAA_;
}
class ClassAAA : public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
~~~~~~~
private:
friend class ClassBBB;
unsigned idAAA;
}
```

Как можно найти объект в векторе `objAAA` по параметру `idAAА`? Каждому объекту в параметр `idAAA` при добавлении в вектор присваивается уникальный номер. Поиск будет осуществляться из `public` метода класса `ClassBBB`.

Comment: Вероятно, значительно проще было бы использовать `std::map` или другой ассоциативный контейнер, а `idAAA` использовать в виде ключа. При этом, если `idAAA` нужен только при добавлении в контейнер, он не должен вовсе являться членом `ClassAAA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример поиска с использованием `C++11`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(objAAA_.begin(),
                       objAAA_.end(),
                       [id](const SHP_ClassAAA& current) { return current->idAAA == id; }
);

if (it != objAAA_.end()) {
    return *it;
} else {
    return nullptr;
}
```

---

Небольшое пояснение по `[id](const SHP_ClassAAA& current) { return current->idAAA == id; }` .

Это выражение является [лямбда-функцией](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), где:

- `[id]` - захватываем в контекст этой функции значение искомого идентификатора,
- `(const SHP_ClassAAA& current)` - аргумент функции, в данном случае это текущий проверяемый элемент вектора,
- `{ return current->idAAA == id; }` - тело функции, собственно проверка совпадения идентификаторов.

Comment: А можно пояснить, что это за конструкция: `[id](const SHP_ClassAAA& current) { return current->idAAA == id; }` 
Я так понимаю, что это "лямбда функция"?

Comment: @Dmitry, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Предлагаю использовать константные версии итераторов (`cbegin` и т.д.), а `return` переписать с тернарным оператором. К тому же, в текущем варианте присутствует ошибка с типами: `*it` имеет тип `SHP_ClassAAA&`, а `nullptr` - `std::nullptr_t`. Если планировалось возвращать указатель, то надо `return *it;` заменить на `return &*it;`.

Comment: `std::find_if` возвращает "iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found. " Соответственно `*it` будет иметь тип `SHP_ClassAAA`, так что запись корректна. Тернарный оператор совершенно ни к чему, только ухудшает читаемость. С `cbegin` согласен, но не обязательно.